# How to align dropdown button to content in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: backbone.js, bootstrap-5, popper.js

I am upgrading bootstrap from 4 to 5. I found that `data-toggle="dropdown"` needs to be changed to `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`.

My problem is after I did the upgrade one of my dropdown boxes shows up on the left side of screen under the button which shows up on the right side of the screen.  They are both in a div tag that should be right aligning and putting them on the right column of two columns.   Can someone help me figure out how to keep the drop down from escaping the div tag. Note: When I resize the page the dropdown box goes where it should be.

```
             <div id="pagetitle" class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <span class="page-title">Claims</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <button id="dropdownCreateNew" type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Create New <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownCreateNew">
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('UB04Detail.aspx?pt=1');">Claim</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('RosterBillDetail.aspx?pt=1');">Roster Bill</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('NOEDetail.aspx?pt=1');">Hospice Notice</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Here is a picture of how how the drop downs look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fthDP.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fthDP.png

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found that when I added an additional div tag after pull-right, that the group stayed together. Don't know why, but it worked.

```
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div>
                            <button id="dropdownCreateNew" type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Create New <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownCreateNew" role="menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('UB04Detail.aspx?pt=1');">Claim</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('RosterBillDetail.aspx?pt=1');">Roster Bill</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="javascript:ClaimWindow('NOEDetail.aspx?pt=1');">Hospice Notice</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```